# As soon as I open the Flutter doc file the command prompt opens only for a second and then it get closed immediately

Tags: flutter, flutter-doctor

I tried opening the Flutter doc file after installing it on Windows 8.1 Pro. I have only tried double-clicking (left mouse) on the file.

Comment: Where is the file and what type is it? And why do you want to open it? I don't think it is supposed to be opened manually.

Comment: It is located here "C:\Users\HP\Documents\flutter\flutter_console.bat" this is the place I installed Futter. The file name is flutter_console.bat

Comment: I just wanted to execute flutter doctor to check whether all the components are installed properly. First I tried executing the flutter doctor command directly on the Command prompt and it also got closed immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is supposed to run flutter doctor the way you are trying.

Usually you open the directoy of your flutter project in the terminal and execute `flutter doctor`.

Please read the documentation for further information: https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows#run-flutter-doctor

Answer (score 0):

I tried opening the flutter_console.bat file by right-clicking and clicking Run as the administrator, it resolved the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).